# How to create button in sprite kit iOS (similar to toggle button)

Tags: ios, button, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a button in sprite kit using SKSpriteNode. I want the button image to change when it is pressed and revert back to old image as soon as the press ends. What i have done till now is following:-

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

self.startTouch = [[touches allObjects][0] locationInNode:self ];
for (UITouch *touch in touches){

        CGPoint position = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:position];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"missileButton"]) {
                TEMissileButtonNode *button = (TEMissileButtonNode*) node;
                button.isPressed = YES;
            }
  }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for (UITouch *touch in touches){

    CGPoint position = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:position];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"missileButton"]) {
        TEMissileButtonNode *button = (TEMissileButtonNode*) node;
        button.isPressed = NO;
    }
}

}
```

inside the update method i am calling this method to check if the touch has ended

```
-(void)changeMissileButton{
if (self.missileButton.isPressed) {
    [self.missileButton addMoreMissileButtons];
    [self.missileButton setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"missileButtonPressed"]];
}else{
    [self.missileButton setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"missileButtonDeselected"]];
    [self.missileButton hideMissileButtons];
}

}
```

The issue is that the touch doesn't get registered at times. Sometimes it works the way i want. When i touch it, its texture changes and when i remove my finger, the texture reverts back to old texture. But most of the times, the button doesn't react to my touch. Am i missing something?

Comment: Where do you call the `changeMissileButton` method?

Comment: Inside the update method of the main scene

Comment: That could be the problem... You are setting the texture 60 times per second! Try using NSLog in the changeMissileButton method for each case, and check how the method behaves while being called from the update: method

Comment: I tried putting NSLog and its printing 60 times per second but the problem is that there is no other way. How else can i detect a change in my button. It is also not a ui button but it is a sprite node. I want the button to change texture back to original as soon as finger is lifted from it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can set the texture in the touchesBegan and touchesEnded method itself.

Comment: I did as you said. Its working the same way as before so i don't need to use update function. But still the original problem remains .. that most of the time the touch is not registered. Also If i long press on the button and then remove my finger, the texture doesn't change back to original.

Comment: Are these touch delegates implemented in the SKScene, or a subclassed SKSpriteNode?

Comment: its implemented in SKScene

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60371/discussion-between-akashg-and-swati-rawat).

Answer (score 0):

Use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded.

touchesBegan - check if the button (SKSpriteNode) contains the touch.  If so, change you button texture.

touchesMoved-  if button does not contain touch, change texture back.

touchesEnded-  if touch stayed within button during touchesMoved, change texture back.

Above is the logic for how to efficiently accomplish what you are trying to do.  Yes, it is annoying Spritekit decided to abandon buttons.